# In C, strtok causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm new to C.

I'm trying to eliminate ".,;?!" from a string using strtok and then to create a simple string without any punctuation marks, but it gives me a 'Segmentation fault' after compilation. Why and how to fix it ?

```
char simple_s[100];
char delim[20];
memset(simple_s,0,100);
memset(delim,0,100);
strcpy(delim,strtok(s,",.;:!? "));
while(delim != NULL) {
  strcat(simple_s,delim);
  strcpy(delim,strtok(NULL,",.;:!? "));
}
printf("%s",simple_s);
```

Comment: `char delim[20];` followed by `memset(delim,0,100);` is not good!

Comment: `strcpy(delim,strtok(s,",.;:!? "));` *before* you check `delim` for `NULL` is not good!

Comment: I removed it but the error persist .

Comment: You removed what? You zeroed the *wrong size*. This is why it's good practice to do it like this: `memset(delim,0,sizeof(delim));`

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what the input is and what the expected output is. I don't think `strtok` works the way you think it works. (Ideally, the input string should be hard-coded in the MCVE itself.)

Comment: I replaced with with `memset(delim,0,sizeof(delim));` but the error remains . I think the loop causes something .

Comment: `while(delim != NULL)`  - this is equivalent with `while(1)`, because `delim` will never be `NULL` (you can't even change it).

Comment: I think I don't understand so good  `strtok` and that's is the biggest problem . I think I misunderstood strtok properties .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delim must be defined as a char *.  Here is your code with a couple of bugs fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char s[100];
  char simple_s[100];
  char *delim;
  strcpy(s, "abc,def");
  memset(simple_s,0,sizeof(simple_s));
  delim = strtok(s,",.;:!? ");
  while(delim != NULL) {
    strcat(simple_s,delim);
    delim = strtok(NULL,",.;:!? ");
  }
  printf("%s",simple_s);
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs `abcdef`

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in the code. First you zero too many bytes with

```
char delim[20];
memset(delim,0,100);
```

To avoid this error, you should use

```
char simple_s[100];
char delim[20];
memset(simple_s,0,sizeof(simple_s));
memset(delim,0,sizeof(delim));
```

Next, you have used the return value of `strtok()` before checking if it is `NULL`

```
strcpy(delim,strtok(s,",.;:!? "));
```

and from there you go on to test `delim` for being `NULL` instead of checking for a `NULL` pointer from `strtok()`

```
while(delim != NULL) {
    strcat(simple_s,delim);
    strcpy(delim,strtok(NULL,",.;:!? "));       // <--- copying from NULL pointer
}
```

but `delim` is not even necessary, you need to work with the pointer returned by `strtok()`. Putting this back together, I would have

```
char simple_s[100] = "";                        // initialise string
char seps[] = ",.;:!? ";                        // added separators, so not to duplicate
char *tok;                                      // added to receive value from strtok()
tok = strtok(s, seps);
while(tok) {                                    // until `NULL` returned
    strcat(simple_s, tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, seps);
}
printf("%s",simple_s);
```

Additionally, I have skipped over the string length checking. When you have it working, check that the new length of `simple_s[]` won't break, before you `strcat()` the next substring.

Comment: Thanks ,  for your time and explanation . Now I understand my mistakes .